# Django Admin and Dajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am new to using anything ajax related, so please excuse my ignorance.

I am working with the example [here](http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/) and trying to get it to work in the Django Admin. I am working on creating a custom change form for the model it will be used in.

The problem I am having is that after making the selection in the first selection box, nothing happens with the second box. I have tried using both prototype and jquery, but it seems that it doesn't get to either of them.
One thing I had to do to even get it to call the function in ajax.py, is I had to add quotes around the Dajax.process variable being passed within onchange.

I am currently just using the django dev server for testing purposes.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you elaborate how you used dajax in django admin? I am having similar problem but can't find any example how this can be done. If you could tell me how you solved the issue or how you used 'django-dynamic-choices', that would be really helpful.

Comment: If I recall, I ended up using https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects instead.

Comment: thanks. any chance you remember how you used it with admin?

Comment: for django-smart-selects, I just followed the example they have listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are several things you'll need to make work together in order to do this:

At minimum:

- A URL pattern to handle your request.
- A view method to return the data in
  whatever form you need.
- A JavaScript file that has the
  event handlers you need, which you
  can add through a form's Media
  property, or by including it in
  the change form template.

Possibly:

- A template to override the built-in
  admin template to suit your needs.
- A custom form class to hold the
  value(s) you Ajax in.

From there, you can use FireBug or Fiddler to make sure you're passing in, and getting back the right values from your Ajax call.

You'll also need to handle editing a record, where you'll need to fire an Ajax call to populate your dynamic form based on the existing value of the object.

Happy coding!

Comment: It appears that the ajax.py function is returning the values it is supposed to, I was able to print them to the console from the script. However the Admin page (change_form.html) isn't refreshing the values for the second select box. Seeing how I pretty much just copied and pasted the example, I figured it should work. Using the same setup for a different example, [here](http://www.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/), it worked just fine. 

Do you have any examples that might shed some light?

Comment: I would recommend using your own code. You'll have a lot tighter control over what's going on. Trying to debug someone else's "black box" can often take more time than it would have to just write your own.

Comment: I found this over the weekend [django-dynamic-choices](https://github.com/charettes/django-dynamic-choices) which might actually do what I am looking for. If not, it may be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. If you've got a better answer, post it. Malicious downvotes suck.